# jQuery Turnbox.JS - Animate without user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really like to use KeiichiroHirai's Turnbox.JS script (http://www.noht.co.jp/turnbox),

However, This script seems only to work with a user clicking/hovering on any button this script is appending itself to.

I wish use these animations when DOM is ready,

I tried:

```
$(function() {
     $.turnBoxLink({
      box: ".example"
    });
});
```

But since I'm posting here, It's obviously not working.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to do that when DOM is ready you should wrap your init code into

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // go when DOM is ready
});
```

or

```
$(window).load(function() {
   // go when page and images are loaded
});
```

And also, Turnbox can be initialized like this :

HTML markup

```
<div class='login_form'>
   <h3>My form element<h3>
</div>
```

With the following code you'll get the extra simple sample, without any options. but for test purposes it could be good to start here :

```
$(".login_form").turnBox();
```

If now, you want to launch the animation at specific event (for example to the ready or load event), you'll be able to do so by using :

```
$(".login_form").turnBoxLink({
  box: ,
  events: "ready", // you can also try 'load'
  dist: "next"
});
```

Comment: @IvankaTodorova yeah you are right. I've completed my answer in order to fit the needs: )

Comment: Is this also possible to time this?

Like on dom ready, wait 2 seconds then run event

Comment: I would suggest to create your custom event, waiting for the ready event, and then making a `on('ready').delay(2000, function() { // your trigger ...})`

Answer (score 1):

After initializing, click the generated `.turnBoxButton` child element:

```
$.turnBoxLink({
    box: ".example"
});
setInterval(function() {
    $(".example .turnBoxButton").click();
}, 1000);
```

This will spin the box every second.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to programmatically trigger a click event on an element with jQuery You can use the [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.sample').turnBox();
   ...
   $('.sample').click();
});
```

Comment: I tried .click() but it wasn't working. I also attached an alert to it.
The alert popped up but the button didn't do anything.